# Generate list using two input value?

Tags: javascript

```
<input id="in1" value="1">
<input id="in2" value="5">

var text = "";
var t = document.querySelector("#in1").value;
var s = document.querySelector("#in2").value;
for (; t < s+1; t++) {
    text += "List " + t + "<br>";
}
```

I got one problem and 1 question.
The problem :
when using `+1` for the loop , the list generated is **1 to 50 instead of 1 to 5**.

The question.
How to add 0 in front of 1 to 9 if `<input id="in2" value="11">`

Result:

```
List 01
List 02
List 03
List 04
List 05
List 06
List 07
List 08
List 09
List 10
List 11
```

Comment: As for your `+1` question, `.value` returns the number as a string, so `s+1` works as string concatenation `'5'+1` = `'51'`. Use `parseInt()` to convert value to a number.

Comment: @adeneo I don't think this is a duplicate of that ?

Comment: he is talking about "The question. How to add 0 in front of 1 to 9",was able to get it to work. Thanks for  answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because  `s` is a String. So s+1 is 51 instead of 6. You have to convert that to integer.

```
for (; t < parseInt(s)+1; t++) {
```